# Typescript compilation is very slow when I use a tsconfig.json file

Tags: typescript

When I run tsc with a project file (tsconfig.json) it takes a very long time (>1 minute) to finish. When I specify the same arguments on the command line or in an arguments file it finishes within seconds. This happens on Mac OS with typescript 2.7.2

This is the tsconfig.json that I use:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "dist", 
    "rootDir": "src",  
    "sourceMap": true
  }
}
```

When I time it using the time command I get the following result:

```
> time tsc --diagnostics -p tsconfig.json

Files:           38
Lines:        34429
Nodes:       157429
Identifiers:  52565
Symbols:      50844
Types:        12929
Memory used: 86147K
I/O read:     0.02s
I/O write:    0.01s
Parse time:   0.64s
Bind time:    0.44s
Check time:   1.91s
Emit time:    0.19s
Total time:   3.19s

real    2m20.611s
user    0m34.914s
sys     1m11.042s
```

It takes more than 2 minutes.

When I create an arguments file that looks like this:

```
--target es2017 --module commonjs --outDir dist --sourcemap
```

And time the command:

```
> time tsc --diagnostics @args src/*

Files:           38
Lines:        34429
Nodes:       157429
Identifiers:  52565
Symbols:      50844
Types:        12929
Memory used: 83773K
I/O read:     0.00s
I/O write:    0.00s
Parse time:   0.52s
Bind time:    0.24s
Check time:   1.10s
Emit time:    0.09s
Total time:   1.96s

real    0m2.259s
user    0m3.568s
sys     0m0.133s
```

Now it only takes 2 seconds, but I don't expect to see a significant difference, because I run typescript with the exact same options. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Can you add `--diagnostics` and post the results?

Comment: Updated the post to add output of --diagnostics

Comment: Apparently there is a big difference between `tsc src/*` and `tsc --rootDir src`.

The project directory contains a lot of other directories besides the `src` subdirectories, e.g. `data`, `dist`, `node_modules` and a couple of others. It looks like even though I specify the a root directory, it still scans other subdirectories.

I can solve the problem by adding all other subdirectories as excludes in the tsconfig.json, but I don't understand why I need to do that. It almost defeats the purpose of specifying `rootDir`.

Comment: Instead of excluding all these folder, how about only including the src folder?
{
    "compilerOptions": { ... },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ]
}

Answer (score -2):

If you have a nexted directory structure, it should be `src/**/*` and not `src/*`

or use `tsc @args --sourceRoot src`

Comment: I don't. It's extremely flat. There are only three files in the src folder. That's what caused me to look at it: tsc took more than a minute on a shallow folder with three files.

Comment: I tried with `yarn tsc --target es5 --module es6 --outDir dist --sourcemap --sourceRoot src` and I'm getting similar times to `tsc -p tsconfig.json`